# Is there documentation for specific Passport.js functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, passport.js, passport-local

I want to implement sessions in my TypeScript project using Passport.js and I am currently implementing the `serializeUser` function. However, I can only find usage examples of various functions and no specific documentation of functions on [passportjs.org](https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/sessions/). For example, they give this implementation of `serializeUser`:

```js
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    return cb(null, user.id);
  });
});
```

I'm wondering whether there exists documentation where I can see what kind of parameters and how many parameters `serializeUser` takes. In the example, they've supplied a function with parameters `(user, cb)` and I would like to know what these parameters are and where they come from, especially since I also want to type them.

---

I also find several tutorials configuring their LocalStrategy like this:

```js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'})
```

and saying things like "The default value of `usernameField` is `username`". I can't find information about the LocalStrategy constructor, its parameters or their default values anywhere. Where should I look?

Comment: All of those packages have their own READMEs, which will likely explain parameters: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#passport-local.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe! I even had that link open in my gazillion tabs... However I still cannot find anything on the parameters of the `serializeUser` function on any README on github